# How to find result whether the graphics card driver supports RGB10X2 colour format or not?

Tags: 3d

I am working on an open source graphics card project. The task is that the open source graphic driver Mesa should support RGB10X2 colour format, which already supports RGB10A2 colour format.
  Also,X is ideally supposed to be representing a default value of 255 as you read in the link given below.

< [What is PixelFormat.RGBX_888](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348053/what-is-pixelformat-rgbx-888) >

But that will require 8 bits to represent,but we have only 2 bits.
Somebody please tell me how to identify RGB10X2 colour format as well as what does X really stands for and how to represent it using 2 bits.
Thanks in advance.