# Opening and saving a .bmp file changes bit depth

Tags: python, opencv, bitmap, bit-depth

I have a file in bitmap format `test.bmp`. When looking at its properties, the bit depth of the file is 32. This is correct, as the file format is supposed to be RGBA.

For test purposes, I open this file using `cv2` and then save it:

```
img_path = os.path.join(path_to_folder, "test.bmp")
img = np.array(cv2.imread(img_path, flags=cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED))
```

When I print the shape, I *lose* information on the alpha channel.

```
img.shape - (1200, 1920, 3)
```

I save the image again to see if the bit depth is conserved:

```
out_f_name = os.path.join(save_to_test, "test_save.bmp")
cv2.imwrite(out_f_name, img)
```

When looking at the bit depth of the saved image, I get **24**.

This is a problem as I **need** an output depth of 32 for further use.

I use version 4.7.0 of `cv2`

Comment: what makes you think the file contains an alpha channel? how do you check that? can you provide a sample file to make this a [mre]? -- imread returns a numpy array already. who taught to you call `np.array()` on that? not rhetorical, I wanna know.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The file should contain an alpha channel otherwise a bit depth of 32 does not make sense, right?

Comment: I'm not seeing data and I'm not seeing evidence that the file _does_ actually contain 32 bits of data. I also can't discount the possibility of a 32 bit format that only uses the RGB bytes, leaving the fourth byte unused. that isn't unheard of for in-memory formats ("RGBx" or whatever, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348053/what-is-pixelformat-rgbx-888). -- in short: [mre] please. upload the file to some place that doesn't convert image files.

Comment: Try flag IMREAD_ANYDEPTH in imread in addition to _UNCHANGED but also keep in mind that imwrite cant save all kind of types. Maybe bmp there is limited to 3 channels and/or 8 bit per channel.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried what you describe, but I'm not able to reproduce the error you are having, for me everithing works well. The original BMP with 4 channels is loaded correctly by OpenCV and when I write the image, the resulting one is with 32 bits depth.

here is my code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img_path = "C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\snail4.bmp"
im = cv.imread(img_path, flags=cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print(im.shape)
(height, width, channels) = im.shape
cv.imshow('original', im)
for i in range(channels):
  s = im[:, :, i]
  cv.imshow(f'channel {i}',s)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

cv.imwrite(img_path[:-4] + '_imwritten.bmp', im)
```

I have python 3.10.4, numpy==1.24.1 and opencv-python==4.7.0.68

hope that helps

Comment: Ugh! What is `im_np = np.array(cv.imread(...))` You already get a Numpy array from `cv.imread()` Please correct that before anyone else gets any crazy ideas

Comment: It was just with the intention of reproduce what @lioncereals did in his code.